# program speed/unnecessary double-counting

Tags: python, performance, cpu-speed

I am trying to find the number of pairs in a list of numbers with a specific difference.  Say, with the list

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

and the difference target '2', I would want to print the number '3' because there are 3 pairs in this sequence with a difference of '2'.  however, my code is super slow - it double-counts all of the pairs, and so I end up needing to divide my solutions by 2 to get the answer.  Is there a way to accomplish this same task without double-counting?  I appreciate any insights you might have.  thanks!  code is printed below

```
    import sys


    def main():
        solutions=0
        pairs=[]
        for i in xrange(len(numbers)):
            for j in xrange(len(numbers)):
                if i!=j:
                    pairs.append([numbers[i], numbers[j]])

        for pair in pairs:
            if abs(pair[0]-pair[1])==k:
                solutions+=1
            else:
                continue
        return solutions/2



    if __name__ == '__main__':
        lines=sys.stdin.readlines()
        n,k=map(int, lines[0].strip().split())
        numbers=map(int, lines[1].strip().split())
        print main()
```

Comment: Will the list always be sorted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each element `i` in `a`, you want to check whether `i-diff` is also in `a`.  For ~O(1) membership testing, we can use a set.  Thus:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> diff = 2
>>> a_set = set(a)
>>> sum(i-diff in a_set for i in a_set)
3
```

which is O(len(a)).

[Note that I've used the fact that `i-diff in a_set`, which is a `bool`, evaluates to `1` as an `int`.  This is equivalent to `sum(1 for i in a_set if i-diff in a_set)`.]

Update: it occurs to me that I've assumed that the numbers are unique.  If they're not, that's okay, we could just use a `collections.Counter` instead to keep the multiplicity information.

Answer (score 0):

If you sort the array, you would be able to find all the pairs just by walking the array instead of doing an O(n^2) search. And the reason for the double counting is that you used `abs` so it's finding not just (1,3) but also (3,1).

Comment: Oh? How do you propose doing it exactly?

Comment: Fair enough, but you do need to construct an entirely separate hash table copy, so there's a memory cost to think of.

Answer (score 0):

Sort the array first, and then for each number(`num`) in the list you need to look for `num-2`. I guess the the fast way to do that is by [`binary search`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm).

So, with binary search you'll get a `O(n log(n))` solution.

Comment: This is still O(n**2). If you use a `set` instead of a `list` it would be substantially faster.

Comment: @Tim agreed, but I also suggested him a `binary search` based solution.